# IIS UrlReWrite to different cross domain

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I would like to use partner mobile website that support custom branding. Here is my URL for mobile as m.example.com

When someone type the above address url i would it to executes url as below

http://partner.com/?autoLogin=true&cssfile=xyz&accountname=example

Is this possible to use url rewrite to achieve result?

Please advise?

Kind Regards
Bhavesh

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible: [Creating a Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite for IIS](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2013/10/24/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis.aspx)

[image]

Replace `10.10.0.50:8111` in this screenshot with `partner.com`, and `tools.mysite.com` with `m.example.com`:

[image]

That should keep `partner.com` from appearing in the URL bar of the user's browser.
Alternatively, if there is no [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) issue, you can put an iframe in the HTML body of `m.example.com`:

```
<iframe src="http://partner.com/?autoLogin=true&cssfile=xyz&accountname=example"></iframe>
```

If you simply want to redirect a user to partner.com, try:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Login redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^/?$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^m\.example\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://partner.com/?autoLogin=true&cssfile=xyz&accountname=example" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```